# How to move an item to front of list in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

In our database, we have a given object that a user can have many of, but 1 is marked as *primary*.
In our Angular 1 app, we list these objects but we always want to show the object marked as *primary* first.

So we have our list of these objects...

```
<object-of-interest ng-repeat="obj in objs"></object-of-interest>
```

The object in json form would look like this if it was the primary object:

```
{
  attr_1: value,
  attr_2: value,
  ...
  primary: true
}
```

or else the primary attribute would be set to *false*.

I am wondering what the best way is to move the *primary* object to the front of the array?

The only way I can seem to find online would be to remove the object from the array then use the `unshift` method to put it in the front of the array, but that seems unclean to me.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `orderBy` filter:

```
<object-of-interest ng-repeat="obj in objs | orderBy:'-primary'"></object-of-interest>
```

Here's an adapted Plunker from Angular's documentation:
http://plnkr.co/edit/T0h4JenpefWYXnul1U3J?p=preview

The documentation can be found here:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can resolve this issue, first is to reorder collection before you display it and this is also most proper way.

Second way is with using additional ng-repeat with ng-show ir ng-if, and this is bad solution.

```
<object-of-interest ng-repeat="obj in objs" ng-show="obj.primary == true"></object-of-interest>
<object-of-interest ng-repeat="obj in objs" ng-show="obj.primary == false"></object-of-interest>
```

I advise you to use first solution, that is, to reorder collection once you received it from API!